# "InactiveInstance" WebJob Status for Continuous and Singleton jobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, continuous

i have created a continuous webjob on azure, and it is running as singleton by adding is_singelton to true in the settings.job.

sometimes, i notice that it gives me status of InativeInstance.

what does this mean? please if any one can describe it simply!

and the reason i have made it singleton, because for some reason the continuous webjob is calling [NoAutomaticTrigger] function multiple times, and because the function i am calling is billing, that is causing in creating multiple invoices for the same subscription, so i have forced to be singleton, so it will work without any issue. but here I am facing another issue which is Inactive Instance.

is there a way that i can solve this issue?

Comment: This is portal error. Don't worry about this status. Actually, it's idea status :) Once your web job has some data to process it will be changed to RUNNING status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bug in what the Portal displays. The Portal ends up asking an arbitrary instance about the WebJob status, and if it happens to hit any instance other than the one that's actually running it, it will be reported as inactive.

But note that despite the incorrect reporting, the WebJob is most likely correctly running on the one singleton instance.

Comment: so you are saying, it is working fine, and i should not worry about it?

Comment: Yes, it most likely is working fine. Do you see it processing whatever it's supposed to do?