# Azure Web Job - Scale out kills existing web job

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I'm looking to use the API to change the number of web job instances I have running based on the size of a processing Q, I know I can setup rules in the portal but the minimum aggregation time is 60 minutes and I don't want to have the system waiting 60 minutes before scaling up if we suddenly get a burst of work.

The issue I have is that currently if I scale out in the portal manually from say 1 to 5 instances it kills the single running instance and then starts 5 new ones.

I assume if I did this through the API the same thing would happen, do you know if there is any way to avoid this?

Thanks

Si

**UPDATE**:
 See below, I submitted 4 jobs and then as the first was processing I scaled out from 1 to 3 instances and this is what happened, the job that Never Finished then reran after the next 3 had finished as it's message would have popped back on the queue because it's processing failed initially.

[image]

Comment: I know this is not a direct answer to your question, but you might want to look at Azure Functions.

Comment: @4c74356b41 hi, I did just look at functions but the web job is pretty heavy duty and I suspect the 1.5GB memory limitation may prevent us from converting the application to a function. Problem is I'm not sure which memory setting in the properties for the webjob is the one to consider, see update above for memory details.

Comment: I believe working set is what you need to look at, virtual memory is the page file? but is that data for each instance? if you scale out almost instantly (like azure functions do) can't you spread the load?

Comment: @4c74356b41 interesting, the issue is we get varying sizes of file to process and so a huge file might need more memory than it's allowed at that point my understanding is that the function dies/stops. Each function would handle a single file, to avoid the file size being an issue I guess we'd need to break out the memory intensive elements into their own functions so we can control how much each function processes....that's a fair chunk of re-architecting though ;-)

Comment: @4c74356b41 I guess the simple test is to try and convert the webjob to a function and give it a try on large files and see what happens!

Comment: For reference and if anyone finds it useful I tried looking at Functions until I found they have a time limit of 5 mins currently after which they timeout so for now Functions are a non-starter as sometimes the task might take 1 min other times 2 hours depending on what it has to process.

Comment: Did you ever resolve?

Comment: @denious Unfortunately not, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

> if I scale out in the portal manually from say 1 to 5 instances it kills the single running instance and then starts 5 new ones.

As my test, if you scale your webjob, it will not kill the single running instance. I created a Webjob template and write a timer trigger in it.

Here is the time I scaled my web app:

[image]

Here is the trigger log in Azure storage ('azure-jobs-host-output'):

[image]

If you find your webjob is running in 'inactive instance' state in Azure webjob dashboard. Please do not worry about it. Your webjob is still in running. Please have a look at David's reply in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406259/inactiveinstance-webjob-status-for-continuous-and-singleton-jobs). Here is a snippet:

*This is actually a bug in what the Portal displays. The Portal ends up asking an arbitrary instance about the WebJob status, and if it happens to hit any instance other than the one that's actually running it, it will be reported as inactive.*

Comment: Hi, maybe I misspoke, the job that was running was I assume killed as it's status on the dashboard ended as Never Finished and that happened at the same instant I increased the count. I assumed that was because the instance was recycled to restart the 5 new ones but given your response I'm now wondering if maybe the dashboard is incorrectly reporting the completion status and that the job did actually finish. I will have to do more testing to confirm.

Comment: Hi Jambor, see my update in the original post showing the job failing due to the scale out request.